# When is the hydra considered a player with the "Face the Hydra" deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

*Face the Hydra* is a special game with special rules which can be found [here](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/Face_the_Hydra).

I know that a spell that deals direct damage to a player cast on the hydra will deal the damage to one of its head. The same applies to trample damage, and so ons, for damages.

But is the hydra considered a player?

For instance, I have a creature that gets +1/+1 counters each time it deals damage to a player. Would that ever be triggered since you attack its heads directly?
What if that creature was unblockable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *is the hydra considered a player?*

Yes, there is a player as normal.

> *For instance, I have a creature that gets +1/+1 counters each time it deals damage to a player. Would that ever be triggered since you attack its heads directly?*

Creatures attacking heads directly deal damages to the heads they attack.

Creatures not attacking heads directly attack the player as normal. However, damage that would be dealt to the player is dealt to a head *instead*. As such, you never actually deal any damage to the player.

In both cases, the attackers deal damage to the heads. The heads are creatures, not players. The ability in question would not trigger.

> *What if that creature was unblockable?*

It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the rules say "You can attack Heads directly with your creatures. Any number of creatures can attack a single Head"

Comment: Sorry, I missed that one. Updated.